# Have difficulties when reading json file on node.js

Tags: json, node.js

I'm newbie of javascript and I want to open json file in node.js.
What's the problem of this "SyntaxError: Unexpected token"?

```
$ cat jsfile
{'key1':'val1', 'key2':'val2'}

obj = require("./jsfile");
jsfile:1
(function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) {
  {'key1':'val1', 'key2':'val2'}
         ^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token :

at exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:53:16)
at Module._compile (module.js:373:25)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:416:10)
at Module.load (module.js:343:32)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:300:12)
at Module.require (module.js:353:17)
at require (internal/module.js:12:17)
at repl:1:7
at REPLServer.defaultEval (repl.js:262:27)
at bound (domain.js:287:14)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your file isn't valid JSON.

JSON strings should be delimited by *double quotes*, not single quotes.

So your file should look like this:

```
{"key1":"val1", "key2":"val2"}
```

Also, JSON files should have a `.json` extension:

```
$ cat jsfile.json
{"key1":"val1", "key2":"val2"}

obj = require('./jsfile.json');
```